# SQL Express under IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, iis

I´m developing a web service that access a SQL Express database, it works very well in the Visual Studio host but when i deploy it to IIS 7.5 i get this exception.

Please help me.

Stack Trace:

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at WSCinema.CinemaService.Movie() in D:\Documents\My Dropbox\Projects\sd.v0910\trab3\code\WSCinema\CinemaService.asmx.cs:line 46
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account that your app's application pool in IIS is running as needs write access to the App_Data folder where your database file (mdf) is stored.  E.g. if the app pool is configured to run as Network Service, give permissions to that account on App_Data folder.

When you run in the VS host your app is running as your user account which has access to App_Data.

Answer (score 1):

You are using RANU, SQL Express user instances. See more details about them at [SQL Server 2005 Express Edition User Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28SQL.90%29.aspx). RANU creates a new instance for each user connecting to the original SQL Express instance, and the new user instance runs under the user credentials. In this case, it will create an user instance under the ASP AppPool identity, and trying to create this user instance hits the error:

> Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server due to failure in
>   retrieving the user's local
>   application data path. Please make
>   sure the user has a local user profile
>   on the computer.

So, if you insist on using user instances, make sure the app pool identity has a profile on the IIS host. But it would be way more beneficial and easier if you abandon user instances, just use the SQL Express instance directly.

Comment: thank you for you question, up vote for you, this was just for a litle school work, i will abandon user instances in my next projects =)